# Javascript выводит форму которая отсутсвует в исходном коде.

Tags: javascript

есть код Javascript  который выводит форму <form...> </form>
Проблема в том что этот код формы отсутствует в исходном коде страницы... подскажите какие команды скрывают его?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите исходный код в дебагере, например в консоли GoogleChrome или FireBug, там вы увидите эту форму и сможете оперативно и быстро понять откуда она берется...
Реально как вариант она просто генерится на событии `onload` средствами javascript, тогда в исходном вы ее не найдете, но на странице она всеравно будет :)

Comment: Генерится на событии onclick(addquestion)
код функции
function addquestion() {
catid = $F('smcatid'), itemid = $F('Itemid');
 var url = smurl+'addquestion&catid='+catid+'&Itemid='+itemid;
 statusElem = $ID('addquestion');
 var d = statusElem.parentNode;
 jx.get(url,response);
 function response(data) {
  statusElem.style.visibility='hidden';
  var f = d.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  f.innerHTML=data;
 }
}
подскажите возможно вам известно как отобразить эту форму в коде...

Answer (score 0):

Тут могут быть различные варианты.

1. Код формы в БД.
2. Код формы в отдельном файле.
3. Код формы скрыт base64

Эти три пунка могут быть переданы как через Ajax, так и через Ahah.

1. `document.createElement('form');`
2. `document.append('<form>');`

и еще 100500 вариантов.

Comment: В любом случае надо смотреть в дебагере

Answer (score 0):

Аяксом могут подгружать, по коду видно:
    **jx.get(url,response);** function response(data) { statusElem.style.visibility='hidden'; var f = d.appendChild(document.createElement('div')); **f.innerHTML=data;**